# NO_DATA_FOUND exception vs FOR loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function to check the **existence of an element** in a table. It returns boolean. I don't want it to raise an error if there is no data.

So I can use **exception**:

```
...
begin
  select 'x'
    into v_res
    from my_table
   where id = v_id;

  return true;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return false;
end;
```

or **loop**:

```
...
begin
  for r in (select 'x'
              from my_table
             where id = v_id)
  loop
    return true;
  end loop;

  return false;
end;
```

This way I don't have to use an extra variable.

**So which one is the best practice?**

Comment: You may use `count(*)` - that never raise exception - and return `true` is th ecout equals `1`... `for loop` is *no good* if you know there is either one or none row...

Answer (score 0):

The first code might return `TOO_MANY_ROWS` you didn't handle. The second loops through the whole `MY_TABLE`, which is inefficient.

`exists` might perform better.

```
select dummy
  into v_res
  from dual
  where exists (select null 
                from my_table
                where id = v_id);
return true;
exception
  when no_data_found then return false;
```

---

You *could* avoid `EXCEPTION` part if you use some kind of a *trick*, e.g.

```
select max(dummy)   --> using an aggregate, you won't get NO_DATA_FOUND
  into v_res
  from dual
  where exists (select null 
                from my_table
                where id = v_id);
return v_res is not null;
```

Though, I guess that `exception` actually *is* the way to handle it as it is obvious what you're doing. That "trick" isn't.